# How do I set the scala compiler version in pants.ini

Tags: pants

I'd like to avoid always adding --scala-platform-version=2.11 to `./pants`. Can I make this the default with configuration in `pants.ini`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that pants options live under scopes, so I needed to have:

```
[scala-platform]
version: 2.11
```

in my `pants.ini` file.

Comment: You can also join the pants slack room for faster turnaround.

https://pantsbuild.github.io/howto_contribute.html

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
[scala]
version: 2.12
```

to yours pants.ini

from [official pants repo example](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pants/blob/master/pants.ini#L307)